# Jupyter lab notebook instance in Google Compute Engine stop execution with a 504 error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-compute-engine, jupyter-lab, http-status-code-504

Hi I have been running code on my Jupyter-lab notebook instances for a while now and all of a sudden I get this problem along with an additional 504 error message.

The program might execute for a bit  (maybe 20 minutes) and then this occurs. Any idea why this is happening?
[image]

Comment: Could be a disk space problem; are you creating lots of intermediate files?

Comment: I a running a loop with about 400 iterations and each time i am creating a new csv where I append a row to it, approximately 10 columns. I have been doing this for a while however and it's been working fine. I have released some disk space however and trying it again. Thanks

Comment: A "csv" as in, an actual file?

Comment: Yes apologies, a csv file.

Comment: In that case, definitely keep an eye out on disk space usage and decrease of it, while running new notebooks, and see whether that appears to be an issue.